# How to enable and disable certain UISegmentedControl segments based on selection in preceding segments

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to enable/disable certain segments in 2 different Segmented Controls based on the selection in the first segmented control the user chooses.

First Segment: Black | Red | Green |

Second Segment: 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|

Third Segment: | 19 | ..... | 36 | 00 |

The functionality I want is that if the user selects Black, then only certain numbers in second and third segment should trigger as .`enabled = YES`

Since Second and Third segments require the initial input of the first segment, I disabled the segments completely in -ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//not sure which one to use and why
[self.secondSegment setEnabled:NO];
//self.secondSegment.enabled = NO;

[self.thirdSegment setEnabled:NO];
//self.thirdSegment.enabled = NO;
}
```

Great, it's now disabled and grey (desired behavior). But when the user taps on "Black" I want certain numbers in the `secondSegment` and `thirdSegment` properties to become enabled for the user to be able to select:

```
- (IBAction)colorChosen:(id)sender {

UISegmentedControl *secondRow = self.secondSegment;
UISegmentedControl *thirdRow = self.thirdSegment;
NSString *colorName;
NSInteger colorIndex = [self.colorChosen selectedSegmentIndex];
if (colorIndex == 0) {
    colorName = @"Black";
} else if (colorIndex == 1) {
    colorName = @"Red";
} else if (colorIndex == 2) {
    colorName = @"Green";
}
//NSLog is correct and displays the correct color when you choose
NSLog(@"%@", colorName);

//red numbers are 1,3,5,7,9, 12,14,16,18  19,21,23,25,27, 30,32,34,36
//greens are 0 and 00

//if they selected "Black" I want to re-enable these segments for the secondRow
if (colorIndex == 0) {
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:2];
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:4];
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:6];
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:8];
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:10];
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:11];
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:13];
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:15];
    [secondRow setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:17];
}
}
```

In the end, I get both segments not enabled (as prepared in ViewDidLoad) and for some reason they will not enable when I explicitly tell each segment individually to enable. I can make the whole secondSegment enabled by simply doing `self.secondSegment.enabled = YES` but I cannot for the life of me figure out why I can't enable specific segments.

Comment: On selecting specific segment e.g., Black load the numbers segment with the elements needed instead of trying to enable each segment in that specific segmented control.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I liked the look of having the options all there, and disabled ones being grayed out and your options being black and bolded, rather than init with the elements needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enable the segmented control first. Then you can enable or disable
individual segments.

Perhaps you should keep the segmented controls enabled all the time, and only
update the individual segments, depending on the color. Something like

```
[secondRow setEnabled:(colorIndex == 2) forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[secondRow setEnabled:(colorIndex == 1) forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[secondRow setEnabled:(colorIndex == 0) forSegmentAtIndex:2];
[secondRow setEnabled:(colorIndex == 1) forSegmentAtIndex:3];
// ...
```

Of course this can be simplified with a loop.

Comment: thank you! worked perfect. once I enabled them, I was able to manually disable the one's I didn't want

Comment: follow up question @MartinR , now selecting the color works and displays only the numbers I wanted, but if I change my color selection (i.e.: select black, then select green) then all the choices get grayed out no matter what. I used else if () statements to see what color the user chose and disabled the ones I didn't want like you mentioned.

Comment: @Nik: Do you also *enable* the ones that were disabled before?

Comment: I think so. In each else if() I began by re-enabling both segmented controls similar to what I did in the beginning of my - (void) colorChosen method. @Martin R

Comment: @Nik: Enabling the control does not automatically enable all segments. - I have updated the answer with a suggestion, perhaps that helps.

Comment: I did your example, and it works flawlessly. You were an immense help. Thank you, I hope this helps anyone else!